# Export of ADF-File does not work. Not with call of exportAreaDescriptionFile() nor with Intent

Tags: java, android, api, google-project-tango

when I try to export a ADF-File i get the following output:

```
09 17:41:56.960 28464-28498/? I/tango: permission_handler.cc:62 App com.bla.editsys has ADF permissions.
12-09 17:41:56.964 28464-28498/? E/tango: file_io.cc:897 Failed to open ADF file: /data/data/com.google.tango/files/Tango/ADFs/007c4016-077d-446f-99ff-fc9ee54072de
12-09 17:41:56.964 28464-28498/? E/tango: file_io.cc:923 Failed to read ADF header.
12-09 17:41:56.964 28464-28498/? E/tango: context_config_utils.cc:269 Couldn't read ADF Info. adf_path = /data/data/com.google.tango/files/Tango/ADFs/007c4016-077d-446f-99ff-fc9ee54072de
12-09 17:41:56.965 28464-28479/? I/tango_client_api: Tango Service: connect, internal status -2
12-09 17:41:56.966 4171-8416/com.bla.editsys E/tango_client_api: TangoErrorType TangoService_connect(void*, TangoConfig): Internal Error: Connect failed internally: -2
12-09 17:41:56.966 4171-8416/com.bla.editsys E/PlaneFittingActivity: Tango invalid exception! Try again!
                                                                          com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoInvalidException
                                                                              at com.google.atap.tangoservice.Tango.throwTangoExceptionIfNeeded(Tango.java:827)
                                                                              at com.google.atap.tangoservice.Tango.connect(Tango.java:435)
                                                                              at com.bla.editsys.PlaneFittingActivity$1.run(PlaneFittingActivity.java:220)
                                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811)
```

This happens if I call

`mTango.exportAreaDescriptionFile(uuid, getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());`

and also this way:

```
Intent exportIntent = new Intent();
                exportIntent.setClassName(INTENT_CLASSPACKAGE, INTENT_IMPORTEXPORT_CLASSNAME);
                exportIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_KEY_SOURCEUUID, uuid);
                exportIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_KEY_DESTINATIONFILE,getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());
                this.startActivityForResult(exportIntent, Tango.TANGO_INTENT_ACTIVITYCODE);
```

Code I got from here: https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/java/java-user-permissions

I work on zeniah, but I cannot check on tablet because I don't know how to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in Zaniah release that causes this problem, this is fixed in A release (the current release).

Under the hood, `mTango.exportAreaDescriptionFile` is calling the intent exactly as you mentioned above, so both methods should be working in A release now.